# The 'New-SmbMapping' command was found in the module 'SmbShare', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: powershell, windows-10, azure-powershell, powershell-5.0, windows-scripting

While running a powershell script, I am getting the following error:

Error provided :

```
The 'New-SmbMapping' command was found in the module 'SmbShare', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SmbShare'.
```

However, SMB-Share is already there in system and Get-SmbShare, Remove-SmbShare, New-SMBShare works if called directly in console.

[Note] Powershell Information :

```
1)Running Powershell version as administrator: Major:5 Minor:1  Build:18362  Revision:752

2)Running the code in windows 10 pro.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to the beginning of your script:

```
Import-Module SmbShare
```

The commands are available in your console because PowerShell *auto imports* them for you. Inside a script, it doesn't auto import the module. You have to explicitly import the module for the cmdlets to be available.

Comment: Thanks HAL9256, but i already have it imported and its available..However, i did put the import statement but could not be loaded again and it gives the same error.